# How to have adjustment layer with black mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

Every time I add an adjustment layer, I have to switch or fill the mask since it is always white.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or an option to change so that an adjustment layer will always have a black mask?

Answer (score 1):

With regular Layer Masks you could hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing it for it to start out black. With Adjustment Layers there's no real way to do that. Fastest way is to hit <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to invert the mask after. If you use the same Adjustment Layers such as an S Curve or a Dodge Adjustment and Burn Adjustment Layers for example than you could make an action to do this in a single press.

Comment: Too bad. Adding it to my things to send to Adobe list. Thanks.